# Maths 4 Quadrant In Grid to specify the value of coordinate in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

Right now i am working on WPF C# application,i wanna to take the point position in grid  using mouse but condition is that  instead of taking origin from **LEFT-TOP** CORNER AS ORIGIN WE SHOULD HAVE TO TAKE **LEFT-BOTTOM** CORNER AS A ORIGIN.

By implementing this i can use Math 4-Quadrant properties which tells, what is the value of X & Y Coordinate i.e. in which quadrant this point is placed.

Comment: You are correct. That's what you need to do. You haven't asked us a question though. So it's hard to say what your problem is. And surely you have already written some code? Perhaps you could show what you have already done?

Comment: Actually, thinking about it further, perhaps you should write the code without the coordinate transform, show us this code, and then we can flip it for you easily.

Comment: P = (mouseX, Grid.ActualHeight - mouseY), where mouse coordinates are relative to the top-left corner of your Grid. If your want a more elegant math convert this to a 3x3 matrix

Comment: @Enigmativity, i have shared the Image of code

Comment: @JatinLavania - Please do not post images of code. Please post your code as text so that we can work with it.